# Explanation needed for double tail recursion

Tags: c, recursion, return, return-value

I am stuck in this recursion with two `return` statement. Can somebody give me the results step by step?

```
caos(9);

int caos( int n ) {
    if (n < 4) {
        return n;
    } else return caos(n-2) + caos(n-4);
}
```

Comment: Get a pencil and a paper, draw things and you'll get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following my comment, I won't give you a full solution but I'll try to help you with something you can begin with.

Let's take `caos(9)`:

```
                         caos(9)    9 < 4? no
                       /         \   
                      /           \
      7 < 4? no  caos(7)          caos(5)  5 < 4? no
                 /    \           /     \
                /      \         /       \
   5 < 4? no caos(5)   caos(3)  caos(3)  caos(1)
             /   \          ↑        ↑        ↑
           ..    ..      all are < 4, let's go up!
                       remember the stop condition. It returns n
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, what you need to understand first is the `return` statement.

As reference, from C99 standard document, chapter 6.8.6.4, paragraph 3,

> If a return statement with an expression is executed, the value of the expression is returned to the caller as the value of the function call expression.

So, when `return caos(n-2) + caos(n-4);` statement will be encountered, `caos()` will be called [again, that's the recursion] with a value of `n-2` and `n-4` as argument.

Now, for the `caos()` function itself,

- if `n` value is `< 4`, it will execute `return 4`
- otherwise, it'll execute `return caos(n-2) + caos(n-4);`

The effect of the later is explained above. Hope this helps.